# On push notification show an activity/popup, instead of the message in the status bar

Tags: android, push-notification

I am an android newbie and i really need your help .On push notification (GCMintentservice) i get to do stuff using pending intent. but I want to show a popup or an activity instead of a push notification message in status bar. That is if the app is running the user will have an activity displayed and NOT a message on status bar. I know its not recommended. But is that possible? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! it is possible. On receiving push message from GCM, use following method:

```
public boolean isForeground(String myPackage) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> runningTaskInfo = manager
                .getRunningTasks(1);

        ComponentName componentInfo = runningTaskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
        if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(myPackage))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

You will come to know if your app is foreground or background. If it is background, show a notification else show an `AlertDialog`.

Above method needs this permission:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

Comment: thank you vinay. let me check this and i will get back.

Comment: can show popup if app is in background with running background service